# How does energy work in Make Me Wonder?

Tags: make-no-wonder

In [Make No Wonder](http://www.matthewhollett.com/wonder/) every action takes some amount of energy. Right now I'm not sure if some things take more energy than others, and I'm also not sure how to restore my energy.

I have found berries the barely replenish it, and although camps restore some energy it seems like every time I use them I restore less and less.

So, how much energy does each action take? How can I reliably restore my energy?

Comment: I just noticed that when the heart symbol next to your energy bar blinks your energy is being restored. But it looks like it stops eventually.